# Cannot open EXE file from webpage. Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: win32exception

I want to call/open .EXE file from my webpage.

Here is the code:

```
Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Users\\MalikMunirah\\Publish\\setup.exe";
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.StartInfo.FileName);
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;          
            process.Start();
```

But after publish the webpage, cannot open the exe file. Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

The exe file will popup after user click the button4 button.